# redirect pdf files .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect an url like that: website_name/download?q=filename.pdf to website_name/resources/filename.pdf

Also, website_name/download?q=filename.pdf is not existing but the users has a chance to find this link so that is why I want to redirect it.

I wrote the following code in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /download?q=$1
  RewriteRule ([^\/]+\.pdf)$ /resources [NC,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

but for some reason it is not working. If anyone has an idea! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but I understand that you want something like this combination of an external redirection and an internal rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from /download?q=file.pdf to /resources/file.pdf
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)q=([^&]+\.pdf)(?:&|$)
RequestRule ^/?download /resources/%1.pdf [R=301]

# internal rewrite from /resources/file.pdf to /download?q=file.pdf
RewriteRule ^/?resources/([^/]+\.pdf)$ /download?q=$1 [END]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: I have an internal server error (http status 500) whenever I am using [END] or [L]

Comment: Also why is it a combination of an external redirection and an internal rewrite? Moreover both links are from the same website.

Comment: An "internal server error" is only the little information your http server hands out to untrusted clients. You need to find the actual issue, you can read that in your http server's error log file. What does it say?

Comment: Such a combination is a typical pattern... It redirects clients still using the "traditional" URLs to the "pretty URLs" and also takes care to map the "pretty URLs" onto the real resources.